# Can Boon of Luck be recharged on a long rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, rests, epic-tier

I was looking at the boons page in the DMG and the Boon of Luck says

> You can add a d10 roll to any ability check, attack roll,
>   or saving throw you make. Once you use this boon, you
>   can't use it again until you finish a short rest.

Even though it doesn't say you can use it again after a long rest, does it recharge after a long rest and a short rest or only a short rest?

Comment: Related  on [Can a long rest immediately follow a short rest to attune to an item?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93472/can-a-long-rest-immediately-follow-a-short-rest-to-attune-to-an-item)

Comment: I'm not asking if one can take a short rest on a long rest. I'm asking if this boon recharges only on a short rest or if a long rest would count.

Comment: It is worth noting that all the epic boons with a recharge use the exact same wording so this applies to all of them as well.

Comment: So should I change the wording around?

Comment: The words are the words. If you are the DM and want to change them, then it's a houserule (which is totally legitimate.) But if you're a player, then discuss with your DM, but be prepared to live with the wording.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Not without DM houseruling

Spells and items do what they say, and [Long Rests and Short Rests](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121865/can-you-short-rest-during-a-long-rest) are separate activities.

This boon resets only a Short Rest. If it reset on a Long Rest, then it would state "Short or Long Rest".

In fact, [Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/983848232777170944) went out of his way to differentiate Short and Long Rest mechanics:

> Short and long rests have different places in the game's narrative, as described in sentence 3 of "Resting" (PH, 186).
>
> Many features are refreshed by a short or long rest. If a long rest included a short rest (it doesn't), such features would refer only to a short rest.

### But will it really matter?

Probably not, but adding an extra hour either before or after a long rest isn't a big deal, either. Up to your table and DM as to whether or not ([or how](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93472/can-a-long-rest-immediately-follow-a-short-rest-to-attune-to-an-item)) you meld those rest mechanics.

Comment: Crawford's tweet seems at odds with the actual text. A short rest is "*at least* one hour long." Well, 8 hours is at least 1 hour long.